# RxJava Subject not repeating with .repeat()?

Tags: rx-java

Can anyone explain this behavior to me?

I'm just learning RxJava and I want to publish my own events to an Observable chain.  But I'm having some issues understanding Subject behavior.

This code:

```
PublishSubject<String> subject = PublishSubject.create();
subject.repeat(3)
       .subscribe(s -> System.out.println("subject emitted %s", s));

subject.onNext("one");
subject.onNext("two");
subject.onNext("three");
subject.onNext("four");
subject.onCompleted();

Observable.just("one", "two", "three", "four")
          .repeat(3)
          .subscribe(s -> System.out.println("observer emitted %s", s));
```

Outputs this:

```
subject emitted one
subject emitted two
subject emitted three
subject emitted four

observer emitted one
observer emitted two
observer emitted three
observer emitted four
observer emitted one
observer emitted two
observer emitted three
observer emitted four
observer emitted one
observer emitted two
observer emitted three
observer emitted four
```

Why is .repeat(3) ignored on the Subject?

Thanks!

Comment: Repeat is not ignored in the subject case but it does nothing because it resubscribes to a terminated subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the first `subscribe`, `repeat` won't subscribe to `PublicSubject` until it receives an `onCompleted`. You can use `doOnSubscribe` and `doOnCompleted` to debug it. Such as

```
    PublishSubject<String> subject = PublishSubject.create();
    subject.doOnSubscribe(() -> System.out.println("subject subscribe"))
            .doOnCompleted(() -> System.out.println("subject onCompleted"))
            .repeat(3)
            .subscribe(s -> System.out.printf("subject emitted %s\n", s));

    subject.onNext("one");
    subject.onNext("two");
    subject.onNext("three");
    subject.onNext("four");
    subject.onCompleted();
```

Here is the execution order:

```
subscribe to PublicSubject
subject.onNext("one") => output "one"
subject.onNext("two") => output "two"
subject.onNext("three") => output "three"
subject.onNext("four") => output "four"
subject.onCompleted() => 
            output "onCompleted"
            subscribe to PublicSubject // a new Observer is added to PublicSubject and PublicSubject is still emitting `onCompleted`, 
                                       // so this new Observer will receive `onCompleted` at once
            output "onCompleted"
            subscribe to PublicSubject // a new Observer is added to PublicSubject and PublicSubject is still emitting `onCompleted`, 
                                       // so this new Observer will receive `onCompleted` at once
            output "onCompleted"
```

Actually, you can use `ReplaySubject` if you want to output all items 3 times.

Comment: I see.  So I was assuming that repeat() accumulated values, then re-emitted them N times when it gets an onComplete().  But that's not the case, it actually does nothing until it gets an onComplete() and then it subscribes and expects its Observable to repeat all the items when it is subscribed to.  Is that a common pattern for operators that require an oncomplete?  (that is, that they just no-op until a complete and then subscribe?)

Comment: More precisely, `repeat()` means subscribe to the source repeatedly. `retry` has a similar pattern. It just subscribes to the source again if any `onError` happens.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use `.asObservable()` like this:

```
subject.asObservable().repeat(3)
       .subscribe(s -> System.out.println("subject emitted %s", s));
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: To be brief , .asObservable() change the subject to the observable。
subject.asObservable().repeat(3) and subject.onnext("one") is just like Observable.just("one").repeat(3). Also you can read the source code using android studio. AS is good.